# Handling a Query Zero Results

Tags: apex, soql

Let me preface with I have used Apex only a little bit.

I have a visual force page that will be hosted on sites publicly.  I take the value of the url string and then query a custom field on the account object to return a few variables to display.  The query works and returns what I need however if I get 0 results I get an error,  I would expect that.  I have been trying to use .size() to catch if no results but can't seem to get the syntax right.  See Code below for 1 variation.

Any help and explanation would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
public class application {

private final Account account;

/** This will return the original URL **/
public String currentURL { get {return site.getOriginalUrl(); } }

/** Remove any slashes **/
public String accountURL { get; set; } {
    if(currentURL.contains('/')) accountURL = currentURL.replace('/','');
    else accountURL = currentURL;
}

public application() {
   account = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL LIMIT 1];  
   if (account.size() == 0) {
       return null;
   } else {
       return account.get(0); 
   }

}

public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
}

}
```

This is the code that worked in case others come across this.

```
public class application {

private final Account account;

/** This will return the origina; URL **/
public String currentURL { get {return site.getOriginalUrl(); } }

/** Remove any slashes **/
public String accountURL { get; set; } {
    if(currentURL.contains('/')) accountURL = currentURL.replace('/','');
    else accountURL = currentURL;
}

public application() {
   List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL LIMIT 1];
   if(accs != null && accs.size() > 0) {
        account = accs[0];
   } else {     
       account = null;
   }
 }

public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
}
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The exception is thrown because you are assigning the results of your query directly to an account, rather than a list of accounts. When you assign the results of a query directly to an instance of a variable Salesforce will throw an exception if the query returns zero rows.

As you are using an instance of an account rather than a list you cannot use the `size` method to test for a valid result.

Personally in this situation I would like to see null assigned to your account variable but that's not how the platform works.

There are a couple of ways of working around this issue. The first is to use a try/catch to handle the flow around this. Whilst often seen on the platform it is generally considered bad practice to use exception handling to manage logic flow - in this case you are expecting the possibility that you won't return any values so this doesn't count as an exception. Anyway for completeness you will often see this;

```
try{
    account = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL LIMIT 1];
} catch(Exception ex){
    account = null;
}
```

A better way to perform this is to assign the results of the query to a list, test the size of the list and react as necessary. Like so:

```
Account acct = null;
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL LIMIT 1];
if(!accs.isEmpty()){
    acct = accs[0];
}
```

Comment: That was a excellent summary of the issue, thank you.

Comment: Great explanation and summary of this issue, helped me solved a similar issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You start by initializing a list where you add your account records to, if the list size is 0 you return null else you return the first result. The problem you had was that you directly created an account and it could be null, however if you work this way your list exists, isn't null, but the contents can be empty. (also I don't think it's possible to have a return statement in your constructor)

in your case you would do this:

```
public class application {

    private final Account account;
    private List<Account> accounts;

    /** This will return the original URL **/
    public String currentURL { get {return site.getOriginalUrl(); } }

    /** Remove any slashes **/
    public String accountURL { get; set; } {
        if(currentURL.contains('/')) accountURL = currentURL.replace('/','');
        else accountURL = currentURL;
    }

    public application() {
       accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL];
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        if (accounts != null && accounts.size() > 0) {
           account = accounts[0];
           return account;
       } else {
           return null;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The results of the query are blank (there's a difference between having a list with 0 rows, with 1 null row in it or the list not even existing.

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, LogoID__c FROM Account WHERE URL_Code__c = :accountURL LIMIT 1];

if(accounts.size() == 0) {
    account = accounts[0];
}
```

Comment: in your case, if you don't get any results, your list will not be initialized and you will get an exception aswel something like: (List has no rows for assignment to SObject) if you initialize your list first, and then add the contents of the query you won't get the exception because your list will not be null

Comment: @PJC blasphemy ;) I say you don't need your "addAll", what a waste of script statements. Run this one: `List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'rubbish' AND isDeleted = true];
System.assert(accs != null);
System.assertEquals(0, accs.size());`

Comment: You could also do:
List<Account> accs = new List<Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'rubbish' AND isDeleted = true]);

The thing is you will get an exception if no results are returned.

Comment: @eyescream I added your code and get "Compile Error: Constructor must not return a value at line 18 column 13" That line is return null;

'

Comment: Brian, just remove whole 'else', updated. @PJC shall we go to a chat room :D Have you actually tried running it with data that will give you no rows. It's really safe that way.

Comment: Thanks guys -- between all 3 of the answers I definitely got a better understanding of what I was doing wrong.  I appreciate it!